# Sync all user clients on university domain

Tags: windows-10, domain, windows-domain

I'm currently attending The University of Alabama in Huntsville. All of the computers here use a Windows 10 domain, and you can log in to any computer just using your student ID and password. Anything you do on one computer is persistent, so I can save a file and it'll stay there after I log out.

However, this is limited to only the single computer. If I log in to another machine I get the standard blank Windows 10 template user. None of my changes.

Is there any way to make it so that I can log in on any workstation and get the same desktop? Or is this not possible without Administrative access?

Alternatively I can just RDP into my desktop in my dorm, but it would be nice to not have to do that.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions involving *issues specific to corporate IT support and networks* are off-topic on this site.

Comment: @Twisty I don't think this would be off-topic in this case, since it should apply to any Windows-based domain, regardless of implementation.

Comment: The reason such questions are off-topic is because the poster has their "hands tied" by their lack of complete administrative control over the environment. This tends to exclude otherwise correct answers, if not totally prevent the question from being answerable. You already have an "answer" that basically confirms this *can* be done, but not by you. That's not really a solution.

Comment: You should speak to the university's helpdesk about this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although what you says is possible (is called [roaming user profiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roaming_user_profile)) that is an option that can be set only by the domain administrator.

Also it's not just flipping a switch, activating that means having a server that can store the user profiles, because they are stored in a central location and downloaded to each computer the first time you open session in that computer (and synchronized back with the central store on logout and again on the next login), so you have to prepare in advance for the extra storage and increased network traffic.

Like you suggested RDP is probably your best option if you want to have always your desktop and files.

*Bonus trivia:* If you ever accessed the hidden folder "C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData" in which applications store their settings and wondered why there are a "Local" and "Roaming" subfolders, that is for roaming profiles. If the computer is joined to a domain with roaming profiles activated the "Roaming" folder gets synchronized with the server but the "Local" folder not (this one is supposed to be used for non essential data that can be quite large, for example the browser cache or downloaded updates).

Comment: Thank you very much! You answered my question. Now is there a way I could use the Roaming profile that DOES get synchronized with the server to have a startup script launch an RDP session with credentials saved?

Comment: The problem is that the roaming folder only gets synchronized if roaming user profiles are active in the domain, I mean, if roaming profiles are active the roaming folder is synchronized, if not nothing get synchronized.

Comment: ah, I see. Oh well, it was worth a shot.